# Sequelize crashing on any find query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a brand new Node app using sequelize, but it won't let me run a single query.

I'm trying to `find` anything and it just doesn't work:

```
var models = require('./models');
models.User.findById(1, { logging: console.log })
```

Every `find` query ends up showing the exact same error. Database has been migrated AND seeded. I verified by opening it up and there are a bunch of users in it.

Here's my model:

```
// user.js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        User.belongsToMany(models.Group, {through: 'Membership'})
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};
```

stack trace:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 1;
/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:28
                    throw err;
                    ^

TypeError: date.indexOf is not a function
    at DATE.parse (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/data-types.js:28:14)
    at /node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:170:36
    at /node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:12572:23
    at /node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4361:15
    at baseForOwn (/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2622:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:12571:7)
    at /node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:134:32
    at Array.map (native)
    at Statement.afterExecute (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:133:39)
--> in Database#all('SELECT `id`, `email`, `name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 1;', [], [Function])
    at /node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:241:36
    at Promise._execute (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:272:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:473:18)
    at new Promise (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
    at executeSql (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:103:19)
    at tryCatcher (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:502:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:683:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:628:18)
    at MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._resolve (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:125:19)
    at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:97:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:564:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
```

---

**Edit:** If I comment out the topmost item in the stack (which is a backwards compatibility thing) it works fine....???????????? Please tell my I'm not crazy.

Comment: Do your DB tables have the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields defined? And are they defined as `datetime`?

Comment: Yep both of those fields exist and are `datetime`

Answer (score 3):

It is important to notice that createdAt and updatedAt are declared by default as `Sequelize.DATE`.

If the database you are using is mysql/sqlite, that should be basically a date string, as you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#data-types).

I got the same error in the past when I seeded my database with entries using `Date.now()`, which returns a number timestamp, for the fields createdAt and updatedAt:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Pokemons', [
      {name: 'bulbasaur', createdAt: Date.now(), updatedAt: Date.now()},/*...*/
    ]);
  },
  /*...*/
};
```

To fix that, change it to `new Date()` which is going to return a date string.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Pokemons', [
      {name: 'bulbasaur', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},/*...*/
    ]);
  },
  /*...*/
};
```

Maybe that is what is going on in your case.

Comment: This happened to me too. In my case, SQLPro for SQLite was converting my date to a timestamp but still showing it as text in the UI. The only reason I noticed was because the dates appeared like `2017/01/25` instead of `2017-01-25` which prompted me to look closer at it.