# TypeError: date.includes is not a function when running any database query with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

When running any kind of query with sequelize I'm getting the error mentioned in the title.

This is my code for querying the data

```
let [userData, created] = await client.databases.userDB.findOrCreate({ 
    where: { 
        robloxId
    },
    defaults: {
        robloxId,
        mnriPoints: amount,
        msdPoints: 0,
        mhctPoints: 0,
        permLevel: 0,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date()
    } 
})
```

I've tried deleting both createdAt and updatedAt, as well as changing the value to new Date().toSting(), new Date().toDateString() etc., but it all yields the same error

When googling the error all I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153846/sequelize-crashing-on-any-find-query), which didn't answer my question

Additionally I'm using sqlite

Here's the full error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iaUP.png)

Comment: Did you try some like `createdAt: '2023-01-28T18:27:53.895Z',
        updatedAt: '2023-01-28T18:27:53.895Z'`?

Comment: Yeah it seems that works, how would I get this programmatically

Comment: new Date().toISOString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153846/sequelize-crashing-on-any-find-query) in case of SQLite you need to pass a date as a string and moreover it should a a date string in ISO format. So you can use `toISOString` method of Date object to get the ISO date string:

```js
const currISODate = new Date().toISOString();
...
  defaults: {
        robloxId,
        mnriPoints: amount,
        msdPoints: 0,
        mhctPoints: 0,
        permLevel: 0,
        createdAt: currISODate,
        updatedAt: currISODate
    }
```